# Background mode for ibeacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I am using tricekit and in their example sdk, I saw these background mode.

[image]

I just need ibeacon to trigger notification to my device and which permission should I allow ?

Last time, I put permission for "Acts as a Bluetooth Le accessory" and app store reject my application. What is the minimum permission that I should allow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No special background modes need to be declared** to detect beacons in the background on iOS.  You don't need location background mode, you don't need bluetooth accessory background mode.  Node of these need to be declared.

**You do need** to get the user to grant background location permission to the app as of iOS 8.  I'm not sure how you do this with tricekit, but on native apps this involves calling `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` and setting a string for the operating system to prompt the user with in the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the application's plist.  This string explains to the user why your app needs location access in the background.

Comment: Thanks you for yr help. I appreciate it.